# HttpResponseMessage not returning file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse

I'm working with a Web Api call that must return an excel file. For that purpose I have an export method which returns the memorystream object corresponding to the list that comes from the body. I could check that the stream returned is well, but I can't open the dialog for the download file. According with [this](https://gist.github.com/joeriks/3714093) post, I'm doing it well, the only difference is that I don't have a path for the file, but I guess that is not necessary.

```
[HttpPost()]
public HttpResponseMessage Export([FromBody]List<SomeClass> someList)
{
      HttpResponseMessage response = null;            

      try
      {
           MemoryStream memoryStream = _someService.Export(someList);

           response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
           response.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
           response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
           response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
           {
                FileName = "LineItemErrors.xlsx"                    
           };

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
           response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
      }

      return response;
}
```

The response message comes with the content property filled and everything else. What am I doing wrong?